# Retrofit library with API the movie DB

Tags: android, api, retrofit, picasso

I want to build a movie app that consumes a REST api using retrofit and displays images using Picasso and bring in Retrofit and show real movie posters as well as detail information for each movie.

i'm using The Movie Database Api to get some real data into our app. Checkout their documentation and get familiar with their API, specially the movies/popular endpoint

But when running the application white screen showing pictures does not show movies and I do not know where is the problem

this MainActivity :

```
package com.walkatheri.movies;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RequestInterceptor;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        final MoviesAdapter mAdapter;


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://api.themoviedb.org/3")
                .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                        request.addEncodedQueryParam("api_key", "MY _KEY");
                    }
                })
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();
        MoviesApiService service = restAdapter.create(MoviesApiService.class);

        service.getPopularMovies(new Callback<Movies.MovieResult>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Movies.MovieResult movieResult, Response response) {
                mAdapter.setMovieList(movieResult.getResults());
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    }
    public static class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public MovieViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        }
    }

    public static class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieViewHolder> {

        List<Movies>MovieList ;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Context mContext;
        public MoviesAdapter(Context context)
        {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.MovieList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        public void setMovieList(List<Movies> movieList)
        {
            this.MovieList=movieList ;
            // The adapter needs to know that the data has changed. If we don't call this, app will crash.
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_movie, parent, false);
            MovieViewHolder viewHolder = new MovieViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;

        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Movies movies = MovieList.get(position);
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(movies.getPoster()).placeholder(R.color.colorAccent)
                    .into(holder.imageView);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

            return (MovieList == null) ? 0 : MovieList.size();
        }
    }
}
```

`Movies` class :

```
package com.walkatheri.movies;

import android.graphics.Movie;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by waad on 08/10/2016.
 */

public class Movies {
    private String title;




    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    private String poster;

    @SerializedName("overview")
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    private String backdrop;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {

        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getPoster() {
        return "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + poster;
    }
  //  public String getPoster() {
       // return "http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQW3LbpT94mtUG1PZIIzJNxmFX399wr_NcvoppJ82k7z99Hx6in";
   // }
    public void setPoster(String poster) {

        this.poster = poster;
    }

    public String getDescription() {

        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getBackdrop() {

        return backdrop;
    }

    public void setBackdrop(String backdrop) {

        this.backdrop = backdrop;
    }

    public static class MovieResult {

        private List<Movies> resulte;

        public List<Movies> getResults() {
            return resulte;

        }
    }}
```

`MoviesApiService` class:

```
package com.walkatheri.movies;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.http.GET;


/**
 * Created by waad on 18/10/2016.
 */

public interface MoviesApiService {
    @GET("/movie/popular")
    void getPopularMovies(Callback<Movies.MovieResult>cb);

}
```

Comment: have you tried debugging or even logging some info to make sure you are getting data from server?

Comment: @Raghunandan I do not know the cause of the problem solved .. I tried but I did not know solved

Comment: then it looks like you want to some one to help you without knowing the problem. We have try your code to figure out the problem. Can you debug and check to narrow the problem

Comment: Does your app crash or do you get any errors. and can you post the response form server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very difficult to point out mistakes without any hint like stacktraces.

Some pointers

1. Use retrofit asynchronous call.
2. You need .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) to convert json to pojos.
3. Image will be loaded only if you us the url http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185"+"yourposterpath". Check the moviedb link
4. Update your libs and change your api accordingly (Recommended)
5. Lastly a clean architecture will help you write tests properly. Your code is unstructured and you need to separate components properly. Suggest you read about MVP or MVVM patterns. Dagger can also help.

A good read about retrofit https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

So the changes

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;

    public static final String MOVIE_DB_API_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor())
                .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(MOVIE_DB_API_URL)
                 .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        MoviesApiService service = restAdapter.create(MoviesApiService.class);


        Call<MoviesList> movieResultCallback = service.getPopularMovies();
        // asynchronous call
        movieResultCallback.enqueue(new Callback<MoviesList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MoviesList> call, Response<MoviesList> response) {

                //int code = response.code();
                // can check the status code 
                mAdapter.setMovieList(response.body().getResults());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MoviesList> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
    public static class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public MovieViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        }
    }

    public static class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieViewHolder> {

        List<Movies>MovieList ;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Context mContext;
        public MoviesAdapter(Context context)
        {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.MovieList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        public void setMovieList(List<Movies> movieList)
        {
            this.MovieList=movieList ;
            // The adapter needs to know that the data has changed. If we don't call this, app will crash.
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            MovieViewHolder viewHolder = new MovieViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;

        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Movies movies = MovieList.get(position);
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185"+movies.getPoster_path()).placeholder(R.color.colorAccent)
                    .into(holder.imageView);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

            return (MovieList == null) ? 0 : MovieList.size();
        }
    }

    public static class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {
        @Override public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

            HttpUrl url = chain.request().url()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .addQueryParameter("api_key", "4848b32592990671646565fa3240a7bc")
                    .build();

            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().url(url).build();;

            long t1 = System.nanoTime();
            String requestLog = String.format("Sending request %s on %s%n%s",
                    request.url(), chain.connection(), request.headers());
            //YLog.d(String.format("Sending request %s on %s%n%s",
            //        request.url(), chain.connection(), request.headers()));
            if(request.method().compareToIgnoreCase("post")==0){
                requestLog ="\n"+requestLog+"\n"+bodyToString(request);
            }
            Log.d("TAG","request"+"\n"+requestLog);

            okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            long t2 = System.nanoTime();

            String responseLog = String.format("Received response for %s in %.1fms%n%s",
                    response.request().url(), (t2 - t1) / 1e6d, response.headers());

            String bodyString = response.body().string();

            Log.d("TAG","response"+"\n"+responseLog+"\n"+bodyString);

            return response.newBuilder()
                    .body(ResponseBody.create(response.body().contentType(), bodyString))
                    .build();
            //return response;
        }
    }

    private static String bodyToString(final Request request) {

        try {
            final Request copy = request.newBuilder().build();
            final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
            if (copy != null && copy.body() != null) // make sure its not null to avoif NPE
                copy.body().writeTo(buffer);
            return buffer.readUtf8();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            return "did not work";
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
public interface MoviesApiService {
    @GET("movie/popular")
    Call<MoviesList> getPopularMovies();

}
```

My Model classes

Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to convert json to pojo

I copied the below for one the respositories on github.

Lots of similar repositories avaiable on github. https://github.com/ewintory/udacity-popular-movies and many more..
    public class Movies implements Parcelable {

```
    private int id,vote_count,favourite,reviewsaved,trailersaved;
    private float vote_average,popularity;

    private String original_language,original_title,overview,release_date,poster_path,title,generids,backdrop_path;
    private boolean video,favored;

    public Movies()
    {

    }

    public void setReviewsaved(int reviewsaved) {
        this.reviewsaved = reviewsaved;
    }

    public void setTrailersaved(int trailersaved) {
        this.trailersaved = trailersaved;
    }

    public int getTrailersaved() {
        return trailersaved;
    }

    public int getReviewsaved() {
        return reviewsaved;
    }

    public void setFavored(boolean favored) {
        this.favored = favored;
    }



    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setVote_count(int vote_count) {
        this.vote_count = vote_count;
    }

    public void setFavourite(int favourite) {
        this.favourite = favourite;
    }

    public void setVote_average(float vote_average) {
        this.vote_average = vote_average;
    }

    public void setOriginal_language(String original_language) {
        this.original_language = original_language;
    }


    public void setOriginal_title(String original_title) {
        this.original_title = original_title;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public void setRelease_date(String release_date) {
        this.release_date = release_date;
    }

    public void setPoster_path(String poster_path) {
        this.poster_path = poster_path;
    }

    public void setPopularity(float popularity) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setGenerids(String generids) {
        this.generids = generids;
    }

    public void setbackdrop_path(String backdrop_path) {
        this.backdrop_path = backdrop_path;
    }

    public void setVideo(boolean video) {
        this.video = video;
    }

    public String getGenerids() {
        return generids;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getVote_count() {
        return vote_count;
    }

    public float getVote_avarage() {
        return vote_average;
    }

    public String getOriginal_language() {
        return original_language;
    }

    public String getOriginal_title() {
        return original_title;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public String getRelease_date() {
        return release_date;
    }

    public String getBackdrop_path() {
        return backdrop_path;
    }

    public int getFavourtite() {
        return favourite;
    }

    public String getPoster_path() {
        return poster_path;
    }

    public float getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public boolean isVideo() {
        return video;
    }

    // Parcelling part

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.original_language);
        dest.writeString(this.original_title);
        dest.writeString(this.overview);
        dest.writeString(this.poster_path);

        dest.writeString(this.generids);
        dest.writeString(this.title);
        dest.writeString(this.release_date);

        dest.writeString(this.backdrop_path);

        dest.writeInt(this.favourite);
        dest.writeInt(this.id);
        dest.writeInt(this.vote_count);
        dest.writeFloat(this.vote_average);
        dest.writeFloat(this.popularity);


    }

    protected Movies(Parcel in) {
        this.original_language = in.readString();
        this.original_title = in.readString();
        this.overview = in.readString();
        this.poster_path = in.readString();
        this.generids = in.readString();
        this.title = in.readString();
        this.release_date = in.readString();
        this.backdrop_path = in.readString();

        this.favourite = in.readInt();
        this.id = in.readInt();
        this.vote_count = in.readInt();
        this.vote_average =in.readFloat();
        this.popularity = in.readFloat();

    }

    public static final Creator<Movies> CREATOR = new Creator<Movies>() {
        public Movies createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Movies(source);
        }

        public Movies[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Movies[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

MoviesList

```
public class MoviesList {

    private int total_pages;

    public int getTotal_pages() {
        return total_pages;
    }

    private ArrayList<Movies> results;

    public ArrayList<Movies> getResults() {
        return results;
    }
}
```

Finally updated libs

```
// Okhttp
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'

//Retrofit and adapters
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

You can check your logs

Answer (score 0):

It's almost impossible to know for sure what's going on, given your vague input, but my bet would be that you haven't specified internet permission in app's manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

(in src/main/AndroidManifest.xml, under manifest tag)